# Python file asks whether batch file to be continued

Tags: python, batch-file

please refer following code, which creates batch file for executing  certain programs synchronously. but after execution of first file, the program stops and asks whether the batch to be continued. This is causing a delay for user input. Since i wish to run several files overnight, the program waits for user input. Could anyone help me with this error ?

```
import os
from subprocess import call

version = "0.1"

os.system('CLS')

print("////////////////////////////////////////////////")
print("// LS-DYNA Simulation Start Script, V" + version + "      //")
print("////////////////////////////////////////////////\n")

input_flag = 0
while input_flag == 0:
   solver_type_string = raw_input("Use single or double precision solver (s/d)?")
   if solver_type_string == "s":
      solver_type_string = "ls971_s_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe"
      print("Choosen Solver: " + solver_type_string + "\n")
      input_flag = 1
       elif solver_type_string == "d":
       solver_type_string = "ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe"
       print("Choosen Solver: " + solver_type_string + "\n")
       input_flag = 1
     else:
       print("Invalid input!\n")


current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
solver_path = "C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\\" + solver_type_string

batch_file = open("sim_start.bat", "w")

batch_file.write("@echo off\n")

sim_counter = 0
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(current_path):
    for sim_file in files:
        if sim_file.endswith((".k", ".dyn")):
            sim_counter = sim_counter + 1
            sim_path = path
            print("Found: \'" + sim_file + "\'")
            batch_file.write("pushd " + sim_path + "\\\n")
            batch_file.write(solver_path + " i=" + sim_path + "\\" + sim_file + "\n")

print "\nDone! Found ", sim_counter, " simulation files in total."

batch_file.close()

print "\nStarting LS-DYNA batch run...\n"

call(current_path + "\sim_start.bat")
```

The created file looks like

```
@echo off

pushd E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw100_amp25_ptr35_matDC04\
C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe i=E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw100_amp25_ptr35_matDC04\t25_nw100_amp25_ptr35_matDC04.dyn
pushd E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw100_amp30_ptr40_matDC04\
C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe i=E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw100_amp30_ptr40_matDC04\t25_nw100_amp30_ptr40_matDC04.dyn
pushd E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp15_ptr25_matDC04\
C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe i=E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp15_ptr25_matDC04\t25_nw10_amp15_ptr25_matDC04.dyn
pushd E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp20_ptr30_matDC04\
C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe i=E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp20_ptr30_matDC04\t25_nw10_amp20_ptr30_matDC04.dyn
pushd E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp25_ptr35_matDC04\
C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe i=E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp25_ptr35_matDC04\t25_nw10_amp25_ptr35_matDC04.dyn
pushd E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp30_ptr40_matDC04\
C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe i=E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw10_amp30_ptr40_matDC04\t25_nw10_amp30_ptr40_matDC04.dyn
pushd E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw30_amp15_ptr25_matDc04\
C:\Programme\LSDyna-971.1\program\ls971_d_R5.1.1_winx64_p.exe i=E:\Shah\CPW\t25_nw30_amp15_ptr25_matDc04\t25_nw30_amp15_ptr25_matDc04.dyn
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual code it'd be a bit difficult to help...

Comment: Show the created batch.  If you use `pushd` without a corresponding `popd` you will get a `stack overflow` error after a while.

Comment: @user3145753 It would nice to share the solution for others having the same problem being able to profit of it...

Comment: And be aware that it is not the python file which asks that, but it seems as if the bat execution process is somehow interrupted...

Comment: Actually the solution i tried with adding POPD is still not working.. Can anyone able to recognise the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I can conclude that, when we press 'ctrl + c' during the batch run (i was  pressing ctrl + c to check the execution time of ls dyna program ), the window of "whether you want to terminate the batch prohgram" appears and program waits for user input..